# Java httpGet page body without css and javascript

Tags: java, html, apache

I am using HttpClient, HttpGet, HttpResponse classes from apache library to get a web page body (html text).

But in response, I am getting something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,
user-scalable=0"
        />
<style>a {
    color: #2EA3F2
}

body {
    color: #666
}

.et_pb_counter_amount,
.et_pb_featured_table
.et_pb_pricing_heading, .et_quote_content, .et_link_content, .et_audio_c
ontent {
    background-color: #2EA3F2
}
```

Here, I can see css and javascript code along with HTML.

**Question:**

Is there any way to get html code without javascript and css, via apache library, by using some sort of headers or metadata?

*P.S. I know about the libraries like jsoup.*

**--edited**
As can I understand -  it's impossible, so question is closed.

Comment: why don't you get the html then remove css and javascript? its relatively easier

Comment: because getting html without css and javascript would be faster, I think

Comment: hmm, if scripts are (are hard written in the html) there is no way of doing it. beside, getting few KB won't make much of difference.

Comment: if it not possible i will parse html and delete css and js, but it's interesting to know the answer on this question for me

Comment: you gotta know, there is no way you can tell the server what to send you.

Comment: I understand it, but i just remeber the opera's ability to disable img loading and some js...

Comment: If you are concerned about speed, then make sure that both your client and server support compression. E.g. request with header "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate".

Comment: @Lauri I test it, and with this header request takes more time then without it

Comment: @JamesSchermann Indeed, time consumption may go up, because some extra work has to be done to compress and decompress data. However if you test it over slow connection (not your localhost) then these extra CPU cycles are outweighted  by savings on data transfer time.

Comment: @Lauri I tested it not on my localhost, but on some website...also yes, I agree with you - I have relative fast internet and upload time increasing because we encode data...anyway it does not fit

Comment: @JamesSchermann I agree that it is not solution for problem you have presented. It was just idea for cases when one needs to downsize data consumption. Since it is not restriction for you, you don't need to worry about it :)